# can you reference a task from an issue in a commit?

Tags: gitlab, commit, issue-tracking

I have an issue on gitlab, `#1`. This issue when it was created it contained two tasks.

Is there a way to mention/reference/close one of the two tasks in a git commit ?

Answer (score 1):

June 2023: Yes with [GitLab 16.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/06/22/gitlab-16-1-released/)

See [issue 396553](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/396553/?_gl=1%2a15gorox%2a_ga%2aMzIxNzQzNzg5LjE2ODg5NzgzNjU.%2a_ga_ENFH3X7M5Y%2aMTY4OTU5OTIxOS4yLjEuMTY4OTU5OTI4OC4wLjAuMA..#note_1396134699) and [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/tasks.html#copy-task-reference):

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/uploads/5fd3ee99e63627358d17dbb970836908/Screenshot_2023-05-18_at_10.13.32_AM.png]

> To refer to a task elsewhere in GitLab, you can use its full URL or a short reference, which looks like `namespace/project-name#123`, where `namespace` is either a group or a username.

---

Aug. 2022: Not yet, but at least you can *define* tasks in an issue now.
This comes with GitLab 15.3 (Aug. 2022)

> ### [Create tasks in issues](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/#create-tasks-in-issues)
>
> **Tasks** provide a robust way to refine an issue into smaller, discrete work units.
>
> Previously in GitLab, you could break down an issue into smaller parts using markdown checklists within the description.
> However, these checklist items could not be easily assigned, labeled, or managed anywhere outside of the description field.
>
> You can now create tasks within issues from the Child Items widget.
> Then, you can open the task directly within the issue to quickly update the title, set the weight, or add a description.
>
> Tasks break down work within projects for GitLab Free and increase the planning hierarchy for our GitLab Premium customers to three levels (epic, issue, and task).
>
> In our next iteration, you will be able to add labels, milestones, and iterations to each task.
>
> Tasks represent our first step toward evolving issues, epics, incidents, requirements, and test cases to **[work items](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/work_items.html)**.
> If you have feedback or suggestions about tasks, please comment on [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/363613).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_3/create-tasks.gif]

See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/tasks.html) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/7103).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

As of GitLab 16.1. you can at least mention/reference individual tasks via commit msg.

The general syntax for this is `namespace/project-name#123` where `namespace` is either a group or a username and `#123` is the ID of your task.

See the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/tasks.html#copy-task-reference).

Comment: Good point. I have updated my answer accordingly.